# Recommendation of analysis textbooks

Tags: analysis, book-recommendation

I'm studying real&complex analysis, functional analysis, measure theory, and Lebesgue integral. I want to make sure which books to use in order to study these fields most rigorously and deeply.

Regarding analysis, I have read the following books and several other less rigorous books which are not listed here: Baby Rudin, Apostol Calculus Vol. 1, Introductory Real Analysis by Kolmogorov, Complex Analysis by Ahlfors, Calculus on Manifords by Spivak

and I'm considering to use the following books: 
Real Analysis by Carothers, Real Analysis by Royden, Functional Analysis by Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis by Rudin, Adams Measure Theory and Probability.

Is going over Carother's book at this moment waste of time? Or is it worthwhile due to its rich problem sets? Is there any flaw in the list of the books which I'm currently considering to use? Which book do you recommend me to read?

Comment: Just a suggestion. You read way too many books. I understand they are good books. But sometimes it helps more to read a single good book multiple times.

On choosing books, it is a common sense that usually the older books are better than the new ones. Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis is a recommended book for learning abstract analysis, at least in several top universities in Hong Kong. You may also want to find a separate treatment on measure theory and topology. Halmos's measure theory is an all time classic. That many people highly recommended it must be for a good reason.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I didn't check Halmos yet, so I will definitely consider it. I always try to finish all the questions on a single book and go on to the next one and sometimes read them back to retain my memory. But I may have to change my style and follow your opinion.

Comment: You're probably right. I found many overlaps between Carothers and Komolgorov and baby Rudin, so I will not use as many texts as I planned to, and I will focus on fewer books.